# how to get column size and type through my database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I've changed column length manually in my previous database.

But after creating new database via HQL it's creating `varchar(255)` and I need to make it longer.

I need to find which table's column should I change?

I can find it manually but now I have about 200 tables and I need a query to do this.

How can I get the column type and its length in Postgres using a SQL query?

Comment: In Postgresql, you can use "varchar" (without a length) or "text" (also without a length) to make a text field that will handle whatever length the text happens to be.  There is seldom a need for fixed-width text fields in Postgreql, since it handles whatever-length strings with grace and efficiency.

Comment: yes, you are right, there is no difference in performance what about the size of data

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/information-schema.html) tables will help you here:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You can examine the `table_name`, `column_name`, `data_type` and `character_maximum_length` columns in the result set.

Answer (score 10):

Stumbled across this old post.  Based on RedFilter's answer here is the query for the original question:

```
select table_name, 
       column_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where data_type = 'character varying' 
  and character_maximum_length = 200
```

putting it together with the alter table syntax of:

```
ALTER TABLE X ALTER COLUMN Y TYPE text;
```

You can generate all the commands you need by running this query:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_name || ' TYPE text;'  
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where data_type = 'character varying' 
  and character_maximum_length = 200;
```

Hope this helps someone in the future, or at least saves them some time!